# Is there a MySQL function written to process sign bits like credit card number?

Tags: mysql, function, checksum

I would like to store some numbers (some serial numbers) and add one check sum- just like how a credit card number is having the last digit.

Is there any port of some algorithm that has been converted into mysql function?

For example:

```
SELECT f_number_is_signed('2424352457'); ==> checks if 7 is valid as check sum
SELECT f_number_sign('242435245'); ==> to return 7 for example
```

FYI, http://www.sitepoint.com/card-validation-class-php/ tells about how to produce a check sum number. I would seek for similar conversion in MySQL function level works.

Comment: Firstly, there is a 10% chance that any number will appear to have the right check digit. See [this](http://www.gefvert.org/site/blog/post/luhn-mod-10-check-digit-algorithm-in-mysql)  for a mysql implementation of luhn.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does support [Bitwise Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-functions.html), however I doesn't not have a specific implementation foor what you are looking for.  The good news is that with the bitwise operators, you should have what you need to [create your own function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html).